# open css popup when page loads completed

Tags: html, css, popup

I have **pure css popup** this pop works onclick button but i need to pop this div when page load is completed

```
<div class="wrap">
        <a href="#modal-one" class="btn btn-big">Modal!</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal" id="modal-one" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h2>Modal in CSS?</h2>
                <a href="#" class="btn-close" aria-hidden="true">×</a>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>One modal example here! :D</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="#" class="btn">Nice!</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

### [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ycc7anhy/)

when page is loaded i need to pop this window automatically and 2nd option by click

can some one help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use javascript and add the extra rules for new class.

Css:

```
.modal:target:before, .modal.loaded:before { ... }
.modal:target .modal-dialog, .modal.loaded .modal-dialog { ... }
```

Js:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $('.modal').addClass('loaded');
    $('.btn-close, .btn').click( function() {
        $('.modal').removeClass('loaded');
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ycc7anhy/2/

A css only solution is to `:target` url for closing popup.

```
.modal:target:before {
    display: none;
}
.modal:before {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}
.modal .modal-dialog {
    background: #fefefe;
    border: #333333 solid 1px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: -200px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 11;
    width: 360px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
    top: 20%;
}
.modal:target .modal-dialog {
    top: -100%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -500%);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, -500%);
    transform: translate(0, -500%);
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ycc7anhy/7/