# CSS riddle, can't figure how to modify piece of code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://fiddle.jshell.net/ycc7anhy/1/show/

Here is live code. Its CSS dialog box.
Problem is, its beign show by:

```
<a href="#modal-one">Modal!</a>
```

By a href element, and I can't figure out how to change it to for example javascript `onclick` or any other method (couple would be appreciated).

Probably this css have to do smth with it:

```
.modal:target:before {
    display: block;
}
.modal:target {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28655684/open-css-popup-when-page-loads-completed

Comment: Similiar problem but in reality diffirent, i need to show this popup by javascript instead of <a href="#modal-one">Modal!</a>. Tryed code from there to work like i want described here but can't.

Answer (score 0):

First, your HTML code should look like this

```
<a onclick="toggle-modal('#mymodal')" > OPEN MODAL </a>

<div Id="mymodal" > your modal content </div>
```

By default, your modal is hidden ( display none, or opacity 0) . Then with a JavaScript function you show the modal.
I prefer use JQuery with JavaScript but you can do it with pure JavaScript.

```
Function toggle-modal(modalID){
    $('#mymodal').classList.toggle('active'); }
```

The CSS class active displays the modal ( display:block ) or set its opacity to 1.

Comment: When im switching working <a href="#modal-one">Modal!</a> to $('#modal-one').classList.toggle('active'); , it doesnt work :/

Comment: Then, try  document.getElementById(mymodal').toggle('active')

Comment: didn't worked, but i developed a way to work around it: window.location.href = "http://webpage.com/index.php#modal-id";, this works